# Understanding the shader workflow in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm having a little bit of trouble conceptualizing the workflow used in a shader-based OpenGL program. While I've never really done any major projects using either the fixed-function or shader-based pipelines, I've started learning and experimenting, and it's become quite clear to me that shaders are the way to go.

However, the fixed-function pipeline makes much more sense to me from an intuitive perspective. Rendering a scene with that method is simple and procedural—like painting a picture. If I want to draw a box, I tell the graphics card to draw a box. If I want a lot of boxes, I draw my box in a loop. The fixed-function pipeline fits well with my established programming tendencies.

These all seem to go out the window with shaders, and this is where I'm hitting a block. A lot of shader-based tutorials show how to, for example, draw a triangle or a cube on the screen, which works fine. However, they don't seem to go into at all how I would apply these concepts in, for example, a game. If I wanted to draw three procedurally generated triangles, would I need three shaders? Obviously not, since that would be infeasible. Still, it's clearly not as simple as just sticking the drawing code in a loop that runs three times.

Therefore, I'm wondering what the "best practices" are for using shaders in game development environments. How many shaders should I have for a simple game? How do I switch between them and use them to render a real scene?

I'm not looking for specifics, just a general understanding. For example, if I had a shader that rendered a circle, how would I reuse that shader to draw different sized circles at different points on the screen? If I want each circle to be a different color, how can I pass some information to the fragment shader for each individual circle?

Comment: "*A lot of shader-based tutorials show how to, for example, draw a triangle or a cube on the screen, which works fine.*" Most tutorials have more than one page, and therefore go beyond simply "draw one object". There are [many tutorials that answer any and all of your questions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides).

Comment: I agree with NB. Read tutorial, get a book, or find some simple game engine and tear it apart. Although the book will be the easiest way to get started with OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas The fact that "most tutorials have more than one page" doesn't necessarily mean that they adequately explain how to do the things I'm interested in. [Your very own tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) is most definitely more than one page, but I cannot find what I'm looking for within the first couple of parts. I guess it could be mentioned in the Illumination section or further, but I'd sort of like to know how to draw multiple objects before I learn how to render lighting.

Comment: @JakeKing: "*I cannot find what I'm looking for within the first couple of parts.*" Then that's your problem. You're not trying to internalize what various tutorials are trying to teach you. You're trying to skip ahead and skim through to pick out some kernel of data. That's not how any tutorial is meant to work. Just like you don't start reading a novel in the middle, you don't start learning by looking for something specific. Just pick a tutorial of decent length and start reading it from beginning to end. When the time comes, you'll see what you're interested in.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you *understand* how rendering works with one object, then you understand enough to know how rendering works with 10 objects. If you know how to pass parameters to a shader for one object, then you know how it works for 30. Going from one to many is a trivial exercise if you *understand* the system you're working with.

Comment: Lastly, as far as my tutorials go, the first multi-object scene comes in [chapter 5](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html). Not that you should read it without having internalized chapters 1-4. And a more complex scene with a camera and many different objects comes in [chapter 7](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2007.html). Which again you shouldn't touch without chapters 1-6.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no conceptual difference between the fixed-function pipeline and the programmable pipeline. The only thing shaders introduce is the ability to program certain stages of the pipeline.

On current hardware you have (for the most part) control over the vertex, primitive assembly, tessellation and fragment stages. Some operations that occur inbetween and after these stages are still fixed-function, such as depth/stencil testing, blending, perspective divide, etc.

Because shaders are actually nothing more than programs that you drop-in to define the input and output of a particular stage, you should think of input to a fragment shader as coming from the output of one of the previous stages. Vertex outputs are interpolated during rasterization and these are often what you're dealing with when you have an `in` variable in a fragment shader.

You can also have program-wide variables, known as uniforms. These variables can be accessed by any stage simply by using the same name in each stage. They do not vary across invocations of a shader, hence the name uniform.

Now you should have enough information to figure out this circle example... you can use a uniform to scale your circle (likely a simple scaling matrix) and you can either rely on per-vertex color or a uniform that defines the color.

Comment: I understand this, and it helps, but I knew a lot of it already, and it still doesn't answer my core question: I'm very confused about how to apply these concepts to a procedurally generated scene. If I want to draw the same thing in multiple spots with most drawing APIs (including the fixed-function pipeline), I stick that code in a loop and use the loop counters to modify the coordinates. I don't understand how to do basic things like that with shaders.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not ranting about shaders being worse, I'm just asserting that they don't seem nearly as intuitive to me as a more traditional drawing system would, and I'm confused about how this is accomplished with the shader system.

Comment: @JakeKing You can use uniform matrices to do this. You might make it so that you have a draw call per-object, each time sending a new transformation matrix to the GLSL program - you can reuse the same program and vertex buffer, just change the state of the matrix much the same as you would if you wanted to change textures for each object. More intelligently, you might use instancing and an array of uniforms or a uniform buffer object. The only thing that changes with a programmable pipeline is how you communicate your intent to transform, it is actually more flexible with shaders.

Comment: @Alexis King You shouldn't necessarily conflate the programmable shader pipeline with the drastic change in API that removed the fixed-function pipeline.  They used to co-exist for a time.  You can even re-implement the old glBegin-style calls in the newer OpenGL APIs, if that makes you more comfortable, and still use shaders.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have shaders that draws circles (ok, you may with the right tricks, but's let's forget it for now, because it is misleading and has very rare and specific uses). Shaders are little programs you write to take care of certain stages of the graphic pipeline, and are more specific than "drawing a circle". 
Generally speaking, every time you make a draw call, you have to tell openGL which shaders to use ( with a call to `glUseProgram` You have to use at least a Vertex Shader and a Fragment Shader. The resulting pipeline will be something like

`Vertex Shader`: the code that is going to be executed for each of the vertices you are going to send to openGL. It will be executed for each indices you sent in the element array, and it will use as input data the correspnding vertex attributes, such as the vertex position, its normal, its uv coordinates, maybe its tangent (if you are doing normal mapping), or whatever you are sending to it. Generally you want to do your geometric calculations here. You can also access uniform variables you set up for your draw call, which are global variables whic are not goin to change per vertex. A typical uniform variable you might watn to use in a vertex shader is the PVM matrix. If you don't use tessellation, the vertex shader will be writing gl_Position, the position which the rasterizer is going to use to create fragments. You can also have the vertex outputs different things (as the uv coordinates, and the normals after you have dealt with thieri geometry), give them to the rasterizer an use them later.

`Rasterization`

`Fragment Shader`: the code that is going to be executed for each fragment (for each pixel if that is more clear). Generally you do here texture sampling and light calculation. You will use the data coming from the vertex shader and the rasterizer, such as the normals (to evaluate diffuse and specular terms) and the uv coordinates (to fetch the right colors form the textures). The texture are going to be uniform, and probably also the parameters of the lights you are evaluating.

Depth Test, Stencil Test. (which you can move before the fragment shader with the early fragments optimization ( http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test )

Blending.

I suggest you to look at this nice program to develop simple shaders http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickshader/ , which has very good examples, also of some more advanced things you won't find on every tutorial.

Comment: "You don't have shaders that draws circles." You can make fragment shader that takes square and draws perfect circle within that square.

Comment: @SigTerm Of course you can, but that's not the purpose of shaders, neither it is useful to understand what the shaders pipeline is all about. With fragment shaders that take "screen quads" and use gl_FragCoord.st you can draw whatever kind of 2d geometry you fancy, but that has not real application in 3d graphics.

Comment: It has practical application if your project needs to draw perfect geometry shapes. In addition to that, you could use base quad to render raytraced object with simulated depth, which isn't that different from a "circle" shader.

Comment: @SigTerm You make a very good point there about the raytraced object. In specific circumstances almost everything has a specific application, but what was asked here was a general understanding, and coming from the fixed pipeline, where calls to stuff like glutSolidSphere where kind of common, I think is best to change mentality and think of the shaders as "per vertex" and "per fragment" code. Edited my answer a bit more.

Comment: @SigTerm: That is the kind of naive approach that results from not learning the programmable graphics pipeline. Since GPUs already have a vertex, primitive assembly and tessellation stage it is cheaper to tackle the issue of drawing a circle with vertices and sub-division and use per-vertex interpolation between the stages than to compute the projected position per-fragment in a fragment shader. That is why the example of drawing a circle is actually a great one for demonstrating how the OpenGL graphics pipeline works. Raytracing certainly is not; I suspect this is the point darius was making.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: "drawing a circle with vertices" That'll be an N-gon, approximation, not a circle. Depending on your circumstances that may or may not be what is needed. Another example would be a subroutine in procedural texture.

Comment: @SigTerm: You can't draw ideal circles in raster graphics no matter what approach you take, so the point is moot. You can't reconstruct a circle without aliasing using rectangular pixels; your technique was not a circle either but a raster approximation.